# Why is there a list object within my list?

Tags: java, android, list

I'm creating an list that stores the latlng positions of images stored in my phone, but when I check the output I notice there are two square brackets at each end.

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WbIkP.jpg)

here is the code:

```
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_photo);

    LatLngs = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.LatLngs);


    List imagePaths = getCameraImages(this);

    List realLatLngs = getLatLong(imagePaths);

    LatLngs.setText(Arrays.toString(new List[]{realLatLngs}));

}

public List<String> getLatLong(List<String> paths) {

    List<String> trueLatLongList = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i< paths.size(); i++){
        String imagePath = paths.get(i);

        String trueLat = ReturnLat(imagePath);
        String trueLng = ReturnLng(imagePath);

        String trueLatLng = "(" + trueLat + ", " + trueLng + ")";


        trueLatLongList.add(i, trueLatLng);
    }
    return trueLatLongList;
}
```

What is wrong that is causing this? Is it the new List I create in the getLatLong() method?

Comment: Replace  `LatLngs.setText(Arrays.toString(new List[]{realLatLngs})); `with `LatLngs.setText(Arrays.toString(realLatLngs));`

Comment: I've tried that, when I hover over realLatLngs on that line it says "cannot resolve method: 'toString(java.util.list)'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A guess:

```
LatLngs.setText(Arrays.toString(new List[]{realLatLngs}));
```

This is creating a new `List[]` containing just one element (the `List realLatLngs`) and then calling `Arrays.toString` on it. You are therefore stringifying an array of lists which would correctly result in `[[...]]`.

Try

```
LatLngs.setText(realLatLngs.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are pushing your list inside an other one, replace `LatLngs.setText(Arrays.toString(new List[]{realLatLngs}));` with `LatLngs.setText(Arrays.toString(realLatLngs));`